# How do i output this correctly

Tags: java

So i managed to create this program but im struggling to  output the boolean lessThan and greatherThan. I tried to create the strings str1 and str2 and mess around with them but i can't get it to work. New to java, sorry!

```
public class Task2{
    
    public static void main (String args []){
        String str = "abccccc23";
        str  = pad (str, 10, '*');
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(str + " {" + timesCharOccures(str, '*') + "}");
        //String str1 = "aoallalaal";
        //String str2 = "bobob"; 
        //System.out.println("lol" + str1 + str2 );
}
    public static String pad(String base, int n, char c){
        while (base.length()<n ){
            base = base +c;
    }
    return base;
    }
    public static int timesCharOccures(String str, char c){
        int counter = 0;
        for( int i=0; i<str.length(); i++ ) {
            if( str.charAt(i) == 'c' ) {
                counter++;          
            }       
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public static boolean lessThan(String str1, String str2){
        {
            return str1.to.LowerCase().compareTo(str2.toLowerCase()) <0;
            
        }
    }
    public static boolean greaterThan(String str1, String str2){
        {
            return str1.to.LowerCase().compareTo(Str2.toLowerCase()) >0;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "...im [sic] struggling to create strings..."?

Comment: You are creating string with code `String str = new String(...)` or `String str = "..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return str1.to.LowerCase().compareTo(str2.toLowerCase()) <0;
```

Replace `str1.to.lowerCase()` the same way you did for `str2`... so `str1.toLowerCase()``

```
return str1.to.LowerCase().compareTo(Str2.toLowerCase()) >0;
```

Replace `Str2` with `str2`.. `Java` is case sensitive..

That should fix the issue I think you meant when saying "*i can't get it to work*"

Comment: Okay thank you but now how i do i get it to output the boolean?

Comment: @MoAlamin calling the method `lessThan` and `greaterThan` will return a boolean value as you are returning a condition. `System.out.println(Task2.lessThan(str1,str2));` would output it value.